# How to identify for which user the stripe webhook route has been called?

Tags: express, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to implement a stripe subscription to my web app. I am using the stripe checkout session for this purpose.

I followed the stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout

Whenever the checkout is completed `checkout.session.completed` event is fired. During this event I want to set `subscriptionStatus` from `false` to `true` in my database. But I am unable to identify for which user the `/webhooks` route has been called.

Here is my code:

```
export const postStripeWebhook = async (req: ExtendedRequest, res: Response) => {
    let data;
    let eventType;
    let event = req.body;
    const webhookSecret = "web hook secret provided by stripe";
    if (webhookSecret) {
        let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature , webhookSecret);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);  //This part is throwing the error
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        
        data = event.data;
        eventType = event.type;
    } else {
       
       
        data = req.body.data;
        eventType = req.body.type;
    }
    let subscription;

    switch (eventType) {
         
       case checkout.session.completed:
       
           //Logic to update subscriptionStatus of the user in the database 

       break;


       //other events are handles




    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

Please guide me on how to identify the user.

Answer (score 2):

Under subscription mode, customer ID can be found under [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer) parameter in `checkout.session.completed` event. You can then use [Customer Retrieval API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve) to find the customer information.

Alternatively, you can [create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) first, then set it in [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer) parameter when [creating a Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create). This allows you to identify the user with `customer` parameter in `checkout.session.completed` event afterwards.

Comment: I think all you have to do is pass in the customer (the user id) when you call stripe.paymentIntents.create()

Comment: Direct Payment Intent (one-time payment) creation is a different integration from Checkout Session integration with Subscription.